# Não consigo criar react app

Tags: javascript, react, windows

eu não consigo instalá-lo. Quando escrevo o comando npx create-react-app ., ele instala algumas dependências, mas depois de algumas, ele aborta toda a instalação e minha internet cai automaticamente, lançando esse erro:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the


Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting site/ from C:\Users\jenni\Documents\catalogoFilme
node:fs:1219
  binding.rmdir(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path));
          ^

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\jenni\Documents\catalogoFilme\site'
    at rmdirSync (node:fs:1219:11)
    at _rmdirSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:235:5)
    at rimrafSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:193:7)
    at Object.rmSync (node:fs:1268:10)
    at Object.removeSync (C:\Users\jenni\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\index.js:15:28)
    at C:\Users\jenni\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:539:14
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\jenni\\Documents\\catalogoFilme\\site'
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

Não consigo entender o que há de errado, plss ajudem